# Remote debugging of Windows Node.js applications on Azure Web Apps or Azure Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have Windows Node.js applications on Azure Web Apps or Azure functions.

It seems that VSC extensions allow us for only Linux.

How do I debug remotely?

Comment: If my answer answered your question, can you [accept it as the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ1gS.png) to end this question?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For azure function, this is impossible now. We need to use Visual Studio to debug but it don't support javascript azure function. VS Code support javascript azure function but it also doesn't have any extension plugins to achieve remote debugging.

For azure web app, the azure app service extension plugin [only support nodejs web app based on linux now](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/remote-debugging).

So the answer of your question is no.